# Is working out with DOMS everyday bad?

Tags: workout-routines, bodybuilding, doms

I'm currently following this bodybuilding workout routine :

- Day 1 : Legs/Abs
- Day 2 : Upper body

6 days a week, with 1 rest day.

This has been nice for the past two months (I'm a beginner) but now, I have DOMS every day and when I have to workout legs and abs, I still have DOMS on legs and abs, same for upper body, even after the rest day.

Is it bad to always have DOMS and never train "fresh" muscles ? Is it an indicator that shows my muscles need more rest ? Should I change to a split routine ?

PS : I'd like to continue 6 days a week because I stopped smoking and working out really helps me not to smoke, it's way harder on rest day.

---

**UPDATE**

I edited the question in order to be more specific on having DOMS everyday, always and never train "fresh" muscles. I don't think this is a duplicate now.

Comment: Doms is not a sufficient indicator here. You can work out with doms, but that doesn't mean that it's absolutely a great idea since you've basically just doing this to torture yourself. I have quit smoking myself and I know how difficult it is, but I hope you have someone on your side checking that you have perfect form and your plan/program is spot on so that you are still able to work out next year ...

Comment: It's not a torture, DOMS are there but it's not hardcore DOMS. If it was torture, i would have changed my routine earlier, I can still workout and perform nicely. As you say, I was wondering if, by working out this way, I will still be able to workout next year

Comment: @Eric I updated the question, I think it's not a duplicate now.

Answer (score 2):

Yes training with DOMS is perfectly fine.

Working out more frequently will make you almost immune to muscle soreness, since I started training everyday I've never experienced muscle soreness again.

[Also Ginger is proven by science to be better than drugs in reducing inflamation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KIFIwec-yEU)
It actually helps with almost any type of pain.

Mind that it doesn't just magically eliminate muscle pain the first time you take, it slowly accelerates recovery day by day until the point where you no more feel soreness.

I had already lost my sensitivity  to DOMS a long time ago by training everyday but I also started using ginger when I increased my leg training volume.

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for your answer but I'm not sure it fits the question. I already train 6 times a week so more training is not really an option (rest day is important) and I'm not complaining about DOMS (it's not that bad, I can live with it). I'm wondering if it's an indicator that I should change my workout, or if it is bad to workout with DOMS. But thanks for the ginger advice, I'll try it